# sort array in fewest operations with k operations

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, backtracking

I was at an interview, and the interviewer asked me to make a function that would find a list of operations that would sort an array in the fewest operations.

The allowed operations were swapping any two numbers in the array.
For example, given the array `[0,3,4,1]`, two possible answers would be

```
[swap(1,2), swap(2,3)]
[swap(2,3), swap(1,2)]
```

I had already seen a question like that [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/), so I solved it with a modified version of the solution there.

However, after that, the interviewer changed the question a bit.
The goal was still to find the shortest list of operations to sort the array, but now the operations were rotating the array to left, rotating the array to the right, and swapping the numbers at index 0 and 1.

I tried to solve it with backtracking and a hash table, but my implementation did not work, and I also feel that there is a general solution to this problem given any k operations. For example, what if we were allowed to swap the two numbers in the middle or to rotate the array by two elements to the left but only one element to the right?

How would you solve this?

Comment: Please add few more examples to make the question clear.